# how to ignore \ in the following code?

Tags: python, simplejson

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> data={'s': 1, 'd': {'kwds': {u'"ramana"': {u'"ramana"': [(0L, 7L)]}}}}
>>> print simplejson.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Then I got like this.

```
{"s": 1, "d": {"kwds": {"\"ramana\"": {"\"ramana\"": [[0, 7]]}}}}
```

But I want to get like:

```
{"s": 1, "d": {"kwds": {""ramana"": {""ramana"": [[0, 7]]}}}}
```

How to do that?

Comment: why do you want to print it without escaping (parsers won’t be able to read it)? do you realize that the actual strings do not contain the ``\``?

Comment: `u'"ramana"'` is quoted, that's why you get an escaped quote. If you don't want the escaped quote then you should have for example `u'ramana'`

Comment: use `print`. `print`.

Comment: But I want to print like that only.

Comment: @user2605977 The result you want is invalid JSON. You'll either have to accept that the double-quotes within the value will be escaped or you need to remove them (`u'ramana'` vs. `u'"ramana"'`). Because, a parser can't distinguish when `"` is used both as the string's delimiters and as characters within the string value without one use being altered (escaped).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a representation of data. You can ignore it.

**Why it is represented like that?**

`""` means an empty string in Python. So, if you have sentence like this

```
Welcome to "SO" Guys
```

When the computer processes it, it might become

```
"Welcome to "SO" Guys"
```

And it will be treated as two different strings (`"Welcome to "` and `" Guys"`). Now, What is `SO`, here? That's why `simplejson` escapes the `"` character with `\`. But the data is safe,

Check this example

```
data = 'Welcome to "SO" Guys'
import simplejson
print simplejson.dumps(data)
print data
```

**Output**

```
"Welcome to \"SO\" Guys"
Welcome to "SO" Guys
```

And `simplejson` does that because of [JSON's specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

> 2.5.  Strings
>
> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the
> C    family of programming languages.  A string begins and ends with
> quotation marks.  All Unicode characters may be placed within the
> quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped:
> quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
> through U+001F).